# Bayesian Network for dummies

Tags: probability, probability-theory, matlab, bayesian-network

I know the Bayes Theorem but I've never heard nor used Bayesian Networks.

Now I'm told to use Bayesian networks to estimate a dysfunction probability in a noisy signal with Matlab

Can someone please post links or simple straightforwarding guides on how to do that? Theory or how to use matlab's toolboxes are equally useful unless they are too generic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bayesian Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) are also known as [Graphical Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model). An excellent (free sample) chapter ([author's](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/PRML/pdf/Bishop-PRML-sample.pdf) or [publisher's](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387310732-c1.pdf) version) on the subject is in Bishop's book, [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/PRML/). See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345280/bayesian-networks-tutorial), the [bnt](http://code.google.com/p/bnt/) toolbox, and example studies such as [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17862-modeling-lung-cancer-diagnosis-using-bayesian-network-inference) one on modeling lung cancer diagnosis. My favorite book on the subject is Borgelt's 2009 2nd edition of [Graphical Models](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-047072210X.html).

Comment: I'm looking at the article "brief introduction.. etc.." and seems very good to get started with. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're to use matlab, the [Bayes Net Toolbox for Matlab](http://code.google.com/p/bnt/) might be useful. Note especially the nice tutorial ["A brief introduction to Bayesian Networks"](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html).

Answer (score 1):

I remember there's a Berkeley AI course covering this. Try search Berkeley CS188 and see if the material is helpful.